# Main subjects to learn Artificial Intelligence in CS

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, generative-model

In my PhD, I will work with ML models. However, I will only use ready-made models as a tool, but I want to delve deeper into Artificial Intelligence not just to use ready-made models, but to understand how it works and create my own AI.

I noticed that most of the content I found talked more about how to use ready-made tools. I am interested in, over time, being the person who 'makes the medicine' and not just the one who 'takes it'.

I was considering doing another degree in Computer Science, but I was hesitant. Doing another degree to learn about AI at the same time as my PhD, I was thinking about using this time I will have during my postgraduate studies to study independently.

I found this [free degree in CS](https://github.com/ossu/computer-science?tab=readme-ov-file), I took a look at the schedule and I don't know if everything is necessary to have this level of knowledge in AI.

Because, at least in Chemistry, many subjects are unnecessary to learn some topics.

Could you help me with what subjects I should take?

Comment: Career path recommendation is off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. But could visit our chat room and ask this question there: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43371/the-singularity

Answer (score 1):

AI is as broad as chemistry.  So the answer will vary based on which sub-field you want to study (Supervised Learning, Unsupervised learning, Reinforcement learning, etc).  Honestly, what one should get out of a CS bachelors can be read in the tea leaves of acceptance criteria for an AI masters program.

In a bachelors one would need:

- Math through linear algebra and multivariate calculus is desirable to understand the underpinnings of modern neural networks.
- A class or two in a high level language programming (Python might be the most ubiquitous in the field).  Learning the basics of Object Oriented-ness will make your code much more flexible.
- A really basic algorithms class is desirable. If you can't identify when something will take O(n^2) time, training will take too long.

From there I would probably go peruse a catalog for a top tier school (MIT, UCLA, JHU, etc) AI masters program to see what the core classes discuss before they let you take electives.  Being a PHD you probably know the drill from there but for the layman, one should figure out what sub-field looks interesting and work through that track progressing from famous textbooks to research papers.